# Burn [.net-framework-version]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Why in the world do we have [.net-framework-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-version) (notice this isn't like [.net-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0))?

It only has about 250 questions and I see no value. The tag excerpt sucks too:

> Versions of .NET Framework. Each version of the framework has betas, final versions, service packs, and patches associated with it.

Comment: It seems to be wildly misused, but I can see a few use cases for people asking about the advantages/disadvantages of specific versions of the .NET framework. Though I suppose those could be closed as off topic for wanting specific software recommendation.

Comment: i would just tag them as .net then.

Comment: It looks like there are a lot of questions asking about how .net versioning works, I agree that these could be edited to just the .net tag.

Comment: Have read a couple of the questions, I am not 100% convinced. It doesn't seem very cut and dry. There are some questions about targeting multiple versions. Would the best thing to tag each version the OP is talking about?

Comment: @AshleyMedway example?

Comment: @AshleyMedway are you saying that one question should use [.net][.net-4.0][.net-4.5][.net-2.0][.net-4.6]? That would be absurd.

Comment: @Braiam that's my point

Comment: @AshleyMedway the only solution that I see to this is that if it isn't strongly (and by that I mean that: if it doesn't have the tag it will *never* be answered) tied to a version, general tags should be preferred and versioned tags avoided like the plague. In fact, version tags should be added to a very small subset of questions.

Comment: @Braiam okay I like that approach. Happy to retag with version tags :)