# What are the reasons for letting the tag [.net-framework] remain a synonym of [.net]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Jeff Atwood has meritoriously argued why a synonym system is desirable on
 Stack Overflow:

> [...] new users can no longer accidentally pollute the tag pool by adding or
>    contributing to yet another oddball variant of an existing tag. Again.
>    And Again. And Again…

-- [Reasons for a synonym system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/01/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)

Which implicitly explains why
 [making .net-framework a synonym tag of .net](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active&search=.net-framework) may have been a good
 idea back in 2011 -- years before the advent of *.NET Core*.

But when
 [Microsoft decided to rename ASP.NET 5 as ASP.NET Core 1.0 (and .NET Core 5 as .NET Core 1.0)](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx),
 Stack Overflow apparently insisted on keeping the tag [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) as a
 synonym of [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net)?

**For what reasons?**

Currently, the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag wiki forcefully prohibits the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag to be
 used as a *collection name* of [the .NET family](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support):

> Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core - use [.net-core] instead. The .NET
>    framework is a software framework designed mainly for the Microsoft Windows
>    operating system.

-- [The tag wiki explicitly forbids using [.net] as a generic tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net/info)

Ironically, just three rows further down on the same wiki page, a link to the
 ***.NET Framework*** confusingly points to .NET advertised as
[Cross-platform. Open source.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) - which at least some of us know is true
 for *.NET Core* but **certainly NOT** for the *.NET Framework*. (!)

It is a fact that
 [the request by Daniel A. White to Burn [.net-framework-version]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314248)
remains unresolved.
- After almost 4 years?
Is this not a strong indication that the issue could benefit from some attention?

You folks who still think that the tag [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) should remain a synonym
 of [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net)
 - could you please clarify your view?

Or else - why not just revert this synonimization and once again allow
 [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) to become a tag standing on its own feet?

Comment: FYI, taking a combative tone ("forgetfulness and neglectedness", "Seriously?") with the people empowered to affect change is unlikely to gain your request or suggestion followers. You may want to consider editing.

Answer (score 9):

Almost every single use of the name ".NET" on this site prior to .NET Core has historically been in reference to the .NET Framework, and it largely continues to do so today, because despite Microsoft's marketese, .NET (Fx) developers are used to it being this way for the last almost 20 years now. Out of **nearly 290,000** [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) questions, only **76** uses of [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) have been remapped to [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) in the last **8 and a half years** (if I'm reading the statistics correctly).

Desynonymizing the tags now isn't going to change that, particularly for older questions. I could choose to rename [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) to [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) before desynonymizing, but I don't know how expensive it would be to do so for 290 thousand questions<sup>1</sup>, or how many hundred or thousand of those questions that aren't about the .NET Fx would be implicated (which would be work of its own to correct).

Then we'd have to educate users to all start using either the full name [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) or a shorthand [.net-fx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-fx) instead of [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), and retag every new question that continues to use [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) in reference to the framework. This would be up to the community whether they feel up to this task. If this change would be too disruptive to the community, I can't make it in good conscience.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I can't just assume that they used tag IDs instead of tag names and that therefore it would only be a cosmetic change, even if they did use tag IDs. I'm not about to make a change that could *potentially* affect 290,000 records in one fell swoop until I am very certain it isn't going to.</sub>

Comment: I had not realized this had even changed. I mean, isn't .NET Core still the .NET Framework, just a different implementation? Maybe not. I haven't touched .NET in several years. I have certainly never heard of ".NET Fx". Your reluctance to push buttons with unknown consequences is admirable. I don't know if I would have the same self-control. Glad to see you back 'round these parts, even if the circumstances don't merit such talent.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I thought ".NET Fx" was a common abbreviation for the .NET Framework, but then I realized it's mostly used internally and not by developers. That's my fault. Also, thanks; though I still consider myself inactive until at least when I'm ready to publish my statement.

Comment: Hmm. Are you now part of the internal team? Also, didn't know a statement was forthcoming. So much that I haven't caught up on!

Comment: @Cody Gray: No, but it shows up in the filesystem, in logs and stuff. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746899/what-is-netfx-in-the-windows-sdk and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624873/what-is-netfx-preprocessor-directive-and-how-to-activate-it Yeah, I decided it was on me to say something after Robert Harvey became the first SO mod to step down. I might be taking up more responsibility over the community's well-being than I really need to, but I can't in good conscience stay silent.

Comment: @BoltClock Ack! *thud* (That needs explaining: the suspense just killed me)

Comment: @Gimby: I'm not going anywhere, but I do feel like I need to say *something* about what's been happening.

Comment: @CodyGray .net framework is the old windows only codebase at v4.8.  .net core is MS's new opensource implementation of .net (vs Mono which is a much older foss .net runtime/library).  Prior to needing to make a few changes to MSIL and the JIT the plan was for .net standard to be a compatibility target for supporting both .net framework and .net core; but the decision not to release a new version of .net framework has meant that .net standard 2 is the last version back compatible to .net framework.  If you think they've made a confusing mess, as someone who still does .net full time I agree.