# How do I unambiguously refer to "the new .NET formerly known as .NET Core"?

Tags: discussion

**Preamble**

In Stack Overflow answers, I sometimes want to refer to "the Core branch of .NET", i.e., the "not Framework" development line containing .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5, .NET 6 and .NET 7, but not, for example, .NET Framework 4.8.

Microsoft would [prefer us to use just ".NET"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/), but that won't work here, since there are *tons* of (old) existing Q&A that use .NET to refer to the .NET *Framework*. [For good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390640/87698), the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag still refers to the .NET Framework.

**Question**

Is there a community consensus on the best term to use in question or answer prose to refer to "the .NET formerly known as .NET Core"? The following ideas come to my mind:

- Continue calling it **.NET Core**: I tried that and got corrected in the comments that I should use just ".NET" instead. Could be confusing if people think you are just taking about .NET Core 1.0-3.1.
- **.NET 5+**: Could be confusing because it mentions an explicit version number, for example in the sentence: "The most recent versions of .NET 5+ include record structs." (They were added in .NET 6.)
- **The .NET formerly known as .NET Core**: Funny once or twice, but probably gets old really fast.

Comment: I mean... just call it what it is. Why be complicated? Old stuff is old. Noone searching for it is gonna call it "The .NET formerly known as .NET Core", they're gonna call it what it is, regardless of what conflicts that has with old stuff.

Comment: @KevinB: The thing is: The .NET Framework is not really old. It's alive and kicking, and it's end-of-support date is further out in the future than the most recent .NET Core version.

Comment: how old it is doesn't change my argument. Calling it something weird or forced that isn't what it's actually called just adds extra shtuff to the post that the user isn't looking for. It doesn't aid in search nor does it make it more findable.

Comment: @KevinB: Point taken. So, what is "what it is"? You propose to just use the new marketing name ".NET" despite the possible ambiguity?

Comment: I plan on continuing to call it .NET Core, because that's what's most understandable to the majority of people. *" I tried that and got corrected in the comments that I should use just ".NET" instead. Could be confusing if people think you are just taking about .NET Core 1.0-3.1."* - Yeah, I don't care much for the people writing those comments.

Comment: The "good reason" .net still refers to .net framework is getting less valid by the year. We should use the least confusing nomenclature, when everyone still thought of the new .net versions as .net core, the status quo was fine, but as more and more developers forget the history of .net and .net framework, not having .net refer to .net but .net framework will become increasingly confusing. Sticking with a different nomenclature than Microsoft is a bad idea in the long run, especially if we use the same terms to mean different things, however confusing Microsoft may make the names.

Comment: If the .NET tag refers to itself as .NET Framework, then it's wrong, and questions that currently use it should be retagged to use a tag that is specifically for .NET Framework.  The official name for the current version of the ".NET Core 7" is `.NET 7`, Microsoft doesn't refer to it as anything else, outside of perhaps the [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core) repository. Microsoft has entire blog posts about the changes to .NET Core and the "next" version of .NET Framework being .NET 6 submitted a few years ago.

Comment: Related: [Untangling the twisted \[.net\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407441/8967612)

Comment: At this point, I think the common perception is that .NET refers to the .NET Standard tech branch. If you want to talk about the framework, you should probably use '.NET Framework' explicitly.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: Do you mean .NET Core? [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is something else.

Comment: @Heinzi End of support for .NET Framework? I thought MS said that .NET Framework 4.8 (the last version) would be supported for the life of Windows. See: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-framework ".NET Framework 4.8 is the latest version of .NET Framework and will continue to be distributed with future releases of Windows. As long as it is installed on a supported version of Windows, .NET Framework 4.8 will continue to also be supported." This is why I still stick with 4.8 for making WinForms consumer apps, since I can guarantee that it's included with Windows.

Comment: The reasoning for excluding .NET 5+ seems somewhat forced/convoluted. If I was to say something like that, I'd say ".NET 6 introduced record structs" and everyone would know that they are there in .NET 6+. I've never had problems discussing .NET with people. Occasionally I might have to add "not Framework", but that's rare. The trick is getting people to tag their questions correctly. If you're asking about .NET Framework, you have to add a tag that matches (e.g. [.net-4.8]) or with a different tag if not (e.g. [.net-6.0] or [.net-core]).

Comment: From a grammatical standpoint, .NET Framework and .NET Core seem like subsets of .NET. For this reason, I don't think just simply calling it .NET will suffice because people that aren't as familiar with the versioning will almost certainly get confused. Repurposing the .NET tag for specifically "the new .NET" also probably won't help much because that's not really something that can be easily policed with the sheer amount of .NET questions being asked (716 just today so far).

Comment: I would argue against that the `.net` tag refers to .NET Framework. Yes, it is correct that most of the questions were probably created at a time when .NET Core didn’t exist. But at the same time, ask yourself the question: Are these questions specific to .NET Framework, or do they apply to all of .NET? I’d assume that a vast majority are not about .NET Framework and still apply to .NET Core. So `.net` is all of .NET, including old (Framework) versions and more recent versions (.NET Core and .NET 5+).

Comment: If you must clarify, a better alternative to the options in your question is ".NET (Core, not Framework)" or even just ".NET (not Framework)".

Comment: Microsoft is so so bad at naming, forget about the Core nonsense, what the hell does ".NET" even mean?!

Comment: @Arad Buzzword compliant circa 2000 or 2001 (I'm assuming the name was picked a fair bit ahead of its Feb 2002 release).

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight: Exactly, it was part of the (failed) [Microsoft .NET marketing strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_.NET_strategy). They even used "Windows .NET Server" as an early name for Windows Server 2003.

Comment: We could just come up with a random symbol that has no pronunciation other than "the .Net formerly known as .Net Core." What could go wrong?

Answer (score 28):

Our organisation, with many legacy .NET Framework projects which we're migrating to .NET 6, suffers from this same dilemma, and we haven't yet found a good way to unambiguously communicate which particular "dialect" of .NET is being discussed either. What I've somewhat settled on is:

- ".NET" as an umbrella term for the entire .NET ecosystem - Framework, Core, Standard, and "new" .NET 5/6/future versions
- ".NET (Core)" when referring to .NET Core, and "new" .NET 5/6/future versions - *the parentheses around "Core" appear to be the magic bullet that satisfies the it's-.NET-not-.NET-Core pedants*
- ".NET Standard" when referring to the now-deprecated standard
- ".NET Framework" when referring to the Framework exclusively

Comment: I like the idea with the parenthesis around Core: simple and elegant.

Comment: ".NET (Core)" does not refer to .NET 5, 6, or future versions, though; those versions were never named ".NET Core". ".NET (Core)" can only refer to... .NET Core, which includes the versions of .NET between .NET Framework 4.x and .NET 5.0. Just call it .NET and specify the version you are working with (so, if Core, .NET Core 3.1 or whatever).

Comment: @TylerH You missed the point. The whole point of putting parentheses around the word "Core" is to imply that it's, in a sense, "optional", meaning that you're referring to either .NET Core or .NET "without Core".

Comment: @Arad No, the point is that it is supposed to clarify, and it does the opposite.

Comment: @TylerH: Well, Microsoft [explicitly states](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/): *"Feel free to continue to use the “.NET Core” name if you prefer it."* So, technically, Microsoft acknowledges ".NET Core" as a valid synonym for ".NET excluding .NET Framework".

Comment: @Heinzi I think that's speaking to individual user preference, not speaking to an official (alternate) name of the tech. As that same paragraph states earlier on, the "Core" part was to specify it was not .NET Framework, and that's no longer needed since there _is_ no .NET Framework v5+.

Comment: How about `.net{,core}` or `.net/core`?

Answer (score 17):

In my experience (over a dozen years of developing in and reading and answering thousands of questions about .NET), it's time to reorganize. Developers, recruiters and managers all over the world have been in a babylonian confusion for long enough.

An oversimplification of what .NET is, or rather, what *most questions about .NET are about*: an ever evolving class library, along with a runtime specification.

#### What we have

- **.NET Framework**: goes from versions 1.0 to 4.8, the latter being supported as long as it comes with Windows, i.e. it's not gone yet.
- **.NET Core**: has versions 1.0 through 3.1, all out of support per December 2022.
- **.NET**: since version 5, it's just called .NET, and currently version 7 is about to be released.
- **.NET Standard**: a kind of in-between layer of *interfaces*, [implemented by .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/).

All of this falls under the nomenclature of ".NET". .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard and .NET have a massive overlap in APIs, especially in what most questions are about.

Then there are **ASP.NET Core** and **Entity Framework Core**: new versions of old components, which will keep "Core" in their name for the foreseeable future to prevent confusion with the .NET Framework variants of the same packages.

#### What *I* think should happen:

1. Make it very clear (in the tag description) that the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag is about the current *and* previous versions of .NET, and that for older questions it may mean .NET Framework. Remove *"Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core or .NET 5+ - use [.net-core] instead."* from the tag description.
2. If a newly asked question is (or presents itself to be) about specific variants (meaning: not applicable to the current (LTS?) version), let users (asker or editor) tag questions with [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework), [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) or [.net-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard) (plus version-specific ones for both), *in addition to* [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net).

#### Motivation:

The .NET Framework is not quite dead, but it's rather frozen in time and won't receive large feature updates anymore, at least not at the same pace as current .NET will.

Because .NET is and will ever be deriving from .NET Framework, and .NET Core is no more being developed. The current name of .NET is .NET, and not .NET Core.

Some parts won't be ported from .NET Framework to .NET, some new parts from .NET will never be backported to .NET Framework.

So assume when people say ".NET", they mean ".NET 5+", unless otherwise specified.

As long as **new** questions are about the common denominator, i.e. functionality present in all frameworks, it's fine to tag with [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), as .NET 5+ **is not .NET Core**. It has more APIs and a different name.

Comment: Is .NET Core 3.1 already out of support? Not yet, I think, happening the end of this year.

Comment: “.NET Core is no more being developed.” - It sort of is, I mean, the GitHub repository has that word in its URL. I agree with everything else you said though

Comment: "*Remove "Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core or .NET 5+ - use [.net-core] instead." from the tag description.*" Absolutely, that last part about .NET 5+ should never have been added in the first place. One misguided user tried to add that in and I fixed that, but it looks like they came back and tried again. I've fixed it yet again.

Comment: .NET Framework isn't exactly frozen, despite what they told us.  4.8.1 was [recently released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481/), and it's not just security fixes. Maybe it's frozen *now*, but they may decide yet again that they need to add something else.

Comment: Thanks @mad, added about that.

Comment: Agree, I bet new developers have not heard about .Net Framework, they simply assume that .Net is .Net 5+.