# What should the guidance for [.net] and [.net-core] be for non-version-specific .NET questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

In updating the guidance for the [.net-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-8.0) tag today, I wrote:

> Use this tag for questions specifically about .NET 8.  For general questions about the .NET 5+ / .NET Core platform, use the [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) tag.  For general questions about the older .NET Framework platform including versions 1.0 through 4.8.1, use the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag.

This is **consistent** with the guidance for the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag, which states:

> Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core - use [.net-core] instead.
>
> ...
>
> (do NOT use the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag for questions about .NET Core).

It is **inconsistent** with the tag guidance for [.net-7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-7.0), which states:

> Use this tag for questions specifically related to version 7.0 of the .NET platform. For questions on .NET Framework generally, use the .net tag.

Which is correct?  Should [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) or [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) be used for non-version-specific questions about the .NET platform moving forward?

There have been previous questions on this topic including:

- *[.NET 5.0 and ASP.NET Core 5.0 tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400924)*
- *[How do I unambiguously refer to "the new .NET formerly known as .NET Core"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420815)*

However their answers seem obsolete because they suggest using a [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) tag for non-version-specific questions relating to the pre-Core .NET Framework.  That tag has subsequently been aliased to [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net).

Comment: Considering .NET 8 and .NET 7 are both  .NET Core I would say your proposed tag description is the better of the two.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's actually inconsistent with what the [tag:.net-7.0] guidance says. ".NET Framework" specifically means the .NET 1.0 - 4.x lineage. It does not include .NET Core or .NET 5+. Though I do think it would be better for the .NET 7 guidance to be updated to the same wording you used for 8. I don't see a disagreement between them, but rather your version is just more complete and useful.

Comment: In my opinion at some point it should be switched around, `.net` for .NET Core / .NET 5+ questions, and `.net-framework` for all framework (.NET 4.X) related questions. It makes sense since the "Core" was dropped from .NET 5+, and there will come a point where newer developers won't know what the "Core" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @ThomasGlaser - I don't disagree in principle, but in practice the [tag:.net-framework] was recently made a synonym for [tag:.net].  So it may be too late to go in that direction, and even if we did, it might be a tremendous amount of work and need moderator support.

Comment: What is the endgame? *.NET Classic* or *Classic .NET*? (Like [ASP Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) and [Classic Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS). *"The introduction of ASP.NET led to use of the term Classic ASP for the original technology."*)

Comment: @PeterMortensen - my endgame is less ambitious: I want to make sure the community is OK with my .NET 8 tag guidance.  If they are I will probably also update the .NET 7 tag guidance, which is lacking.